# Add padding to table cells using iTextPdf

Tags: java, itext

Following is a demo code to generate a PDF doc from a HTML source:

```
public class SimpleAdhocReport
{
public SimpleAdhocReport()
{
    build();
}

private void build()
{
    AdhocConfiguration configuration = new AdhocConfiguration();
    AdhocReport report = new AdhocReport();
    configuration.setReport(report);

    AdhocColumn column = new AdhocColumn();
    column.setName("item");
    report.addColumn(column);

    column = new AdhocColumn();
    column.setName("orderdate");
    report.addColumn(column);

    column = new AdhocColumn();
    column.setName("quantity");
    report.addColumn(column);

    column = new AdhocColumn();
    column.setName("unitprice");
    report.addColumn(column);

    try
    {
        AdhocManager.saveConfiguration(configuration, new FileOutputStream("d:/configuration.xml"));
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        AdhocConfiguration loadedConfiguration = AdhocManager.loadConfiguration(new FileInputStream("d:/configuration.xml"));

        JasperReportBuilder reportBuilder = AdhocManager.createReport(configuration.getReport());
        reportBuilder.setDataSource(createDataSource());

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        reportBuilder.toHtml(baos);
        String html = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
        baos.close();

        Whitelist wl = Whitelist.simpleText();
        wl.addTags("table", "tr", "td");
        String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, wl);

        clean = clean.replace("<td></td>", "");
        clean = clean.replace("<td> </td>", "");
        clean = clean.replace("<td> ", "<td>");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(clean);
        for (Element element : doc.select("*"))
        {
            if (!element.hasText() && element.isBlock())
            {
                element.remove();
            }
        }

        clean = doc.body().html();

        int startIndex = clean.indexOf("<table>", 6);
        int endIndex = clean.indexOf("</table>");
        clean = clean.substring(startIndex, endIndex + 8);

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(("d:/test.html")));
        writer.write(clean);

        writer.close();

        try
        {
            createPdf(clean);
        }
        catch (DocumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    catch (DRException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private JRDataSource createDataSource()
{
    DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("item", "orderdate", "quantity", "unitprice");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        dataSource.add("Book", new Date(), (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1,
                new BigDecimal(Math.random() * 100 + 1).setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP));
    }
    return dataSource;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new SimpleAdhocReport();
}

public void createPdf(String html) throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER);
    document.setMargins(30, 30, 80, 30);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\HTMLtoPDF.pdf"));
    document.open();

    PdfPTable table = null;
    ElementList list = com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(html, null);
    for (com.itextpdf.text.Element element : list)
    {
        table = new PdfPTable((PdfPTable) element);
    }
    table.setWidthPercentage(100);
    ArrayList<PdfPRow> rows = table.getRows();

    for (PdfPRow rw : rows)
    {
        PdfPCell[] cells = rw.getCells();
        for (PdfPCell cl : cells)
        {
            cl.setVerticalAlignment(com.itextpdf.text.Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
            cl.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
            cl.setNoWrap(true);
            cl.setPadding(10f);
            cl.setCellEvent(new MyCell());
        }
    }

    document.add(table);

    document.close();
}
}

class MyCell implements PdfPCellEvent
{
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position, PdfContentByte[] canvases)
    {
        float x1 = position.getLeft() - 2;
        float x2 = position.getRight() + 2;
        float y1 = position.getTop() + 2;
        float y2 = position.getBottom() - 2;
        PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        canvas.rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        canvas.stroke();
    }
}
```

I am working with jasper reports to create a adhoc report and generate the HTML from there. I have to generate a PDF from this HTML.

Couple of issue I am facing, any help is appreciated:

1. I am setting the

   table.setWidthPercentage(100);

for a page with table its not working.

2. I have to increase spacing between columns. Tried what Bruno suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391037/is-it-possible-to-have-space-between-cells-in-itextpdf). Its not working. I have also tried using a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574020/itext-java-table-cellspacing) with no luck. Ref. image below.
3. Also if i cell event to default is not working.

e.g.

```
table.getDefaultCell().setCellEvent()
```

Any suggestions ?

Update:

My Output [image: Generated PDF]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: There is not error. PDF is getting generated. Let me see if i can add a screen shot of generated PDF.

Comment: Can you not use iReport designer to design the page and use it?

Comment: @Isiva i am not using it. I am using **Jsoup** library to clean out all the formatting. the end htmlis generated as `<table> 
     <tbody>  
      <tr> 
       <td>item</td> 
       <td>orderdate</td> 
       <td>quantity</td> 
       <td>unitprice</td> 
      </tr> ` like this.

Comment: Looks like the tags are not propertly closed. Remove the JSOUP clean up and give a try, it it works then fix the clean up code.What I mean is pass the html as is to jasper and see if it works.

Comment: Dynamic report generated too much of unnecessary code in HTML. I have tried with clean up and its just keeps failing. Hence I had to clean it it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the padding as i want by parsing the HTML following way:

```
public PdfPTable getTable(String cleanHTML) throws IOException
{
    String CSS = "tr { text-align: center; } td { padding: 5px; }";

    CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.getCSS(new ByteArrayInputStream(CSS.getBytes()));
    cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

    // HTML
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

    // Pipelines
    ElementList elements = new ElementList();
    ElementHandlerPipeline pdf = new ElementHandlerPipeline(elements, null);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

    // XML Worker
    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(cleanHTML.getBytes()));

    return (PdfPTable) elements.get(0);
}
```

That fixes the issue mentioned in question 2. Q3 is not longer required.